# how to edit Evernote's ENML file, especially adding / modifying width and height tag in <en-media> tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xhtml, evernote

I would like to add or edit height and width values in en-media tags for all my Evernote notes.
The idea is to make the notes more readable by making the image to display as a smaller image when the note is rendered, but for the image to stay the original size it was when it was attached to the note.

```
<en-media type="image/jpg" hash="a2a50c9d6aab3f1f19c9d001f771d942" height="200" width="200" />
```

Is there a python library or what would be the best approach to edit note.content that is obtained using noteStore.getNote, and then presumably the edited note can be updated using noteStore.updateNote.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a (simplified) version of your enml file, before and after the edit?

Comment: I did not know to play with xml.etree.ElementTree when I wrote the question. Now it all makes sense. @JackFleeting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

en_xml = '''<doc><en-media type="image/jpg" hash="a2a50c9d6aab3f1f19c9d001f771d942" height="200" width="200" /></doc>'''

new_height = '300'
new_width = '300'

root = ET.fromstring(en_xml)

media = root.find('.//en-media')
media.attrib['height'] = new_height
media.attrib['width'] = new_width

ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<doc><en-media hash="a2a50c9d6aab3f1f19c9d001f771d942" height="300" type="image/jpg" width="300" /></doc>
```

Comment: Thank you this works. And I guess I can use root.findall to get a list of all media tags, and then in a loop set the attribute for each of those media tags. Will try that.